# Does BigQuery support nanoseconds in any of its date time data type?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have done some research on **DATETIME** and **TIMESTAMP** data type and I understand that they support date time to be represented in milliseconds and microseconds

like the one below,

```
YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]]
```

But, is it possible to load/represent values that has nanoseconds precision?

like,

```
YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDDDDD]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, BigQuery supports up to microsecond precision, and not only millisecond.

No, I don't believe it supports nanosecond precision (maybe a Googler will correct me there), and I certainly can't see anything in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting). However, this is stated:

> An error is produced if the string_expression is invalid, has more
>   than six subsecond digits (i.e. precision greater than microseconds),
>   or represents a time outside of the supported timestamp range.

Thus, this will work:

```
SELECT CAST('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

But this will not (*"Could not cast literal "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000000" to type TIMESTAMP"*):

```
SELECT CAST('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000000' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: You are correct, both TIMESTAMP and DATETIME go up to microsecond precision. It will be interesting to know what kind of device does OP have which allows measuring nanosecond precision in distributed environments.

Answer (score 2):

For more context on timestamp precision, consider the [supported range of BigQuery timestamps](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type), which is `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999`. With microsecond precision, if you anchor timestamps to the Unix epoch, this means that you can represent the start of this range with the integer value `-62135596800000000` and the end with `253402300799999999` (these are the values that you get if you apply the `UNIX_MICROS` function to the timestamps above).

Now suppose that we wanted nanosecond precision, but we still wanted to be able to express the timestamp as an integer relative to the Unix epoch. The minimum and maximum timestamps would be represented as `-62135596800000000000` and `253402300799999999`. Looking at the range of int64, though, we would need a wider integer type, since the min and max of int64 are `-9223372036854775808` and `9223372036854775807`. Alternatively, we would need to restrict the range of timestamps to approximately `1677-09-21 00:12:43` to `2262-04-11 23:47:16`, assuming I did the math correctly. Given that nanosecond precision generally isn't that useful, having the wider timestamp range while still being able to use a 64-bit representation is the best compromise.